# Under exactly which circumstances will silent sign-in fail?

Tags: android, authorization, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

I have started integrating [Account Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050048870?ha_source=hms1), but have many questions.

Initially i wanted to use a refresh token to refresh the user's session, but now i realised i can use silent sign-in instead.

I`m wondering exactly under which circumstances the silent sign-in might fail.

I have read this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/faq-0000001050048966?ha_source=hms1):

[image]

after 10.000 silent sign-ins, it will fail. Does something like this happen? Is silent sign-in related to the validity of the refresh token?

I think the silent sign-in will only fail if the user has not logged in before or has not authorized all the requested scopes.

I don't know if my guess is correct. Does anyone else know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i figured out the problem.

---

Silent sign fails only in the following scenarios (in this scenarios an error code is returned and the login page is not displayed):

1. The user first login the app.
2. The system account is not logged in.

Can use the authorization-code mode:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/app-login-authorization-code-0000001050193881-V5#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001063940385__section1234212547126?ha_source=hms1

When get the authorization code you can get AT and RT from server, after the AT is expired, you can get a new AT by RT. The invoking limit does not affect the invoking of the SDK on the device side.

[image]